# How to update everything to Twitter Bootstrap 3?

Tags: update, joomla-3.x, twitter-bootstrap-2, twitter-bootstrap-3

I made a template which used Twitter Bootstrap 3, and the front end worked ok, until I had the edit views in the front end, which depend greatly in Twitter Bootstrap 2 due to the way Joomla has been since version 3, I had to revert my styles to Twitter Bootstrap 2 so that it worked correctly in the short term.

How can I update all to Twitter Bootstrap 3 and remove dependencies to version 2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not sure but use this rereplacer joomla extension

refer this link,

http://www.nonumber.nl/extensions/rereplacer

otherwise, Template overrides are the only way to do this.

Comment: See this for a step by step guide on use rereplacer http://www.joostrap.com/support/tutorials-videos/206-boostrap2-to-bootstrap3-super-easy-update

Comment: @GeorgeWilson Would this method slow down the site much?

Comment: @moomoochoo it wouldn't be super awful. But there will be a performance impact of course

Answer (score 6):

Template overrides are the only way to do this. In terms of the form fields we're working on creating JLayouts for these form fields so you can override them (see https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/pull/3231).

However currently as @Anibal says this isn't possible in J3.2.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look on [this admin template](https://github.com/asika32764/joomla-bootstrap3-isis-template) - it is `Isis` converted to Bootstrap 3. May be you can take some ideas from there. Moreover this template supports both Bootstrap 2 & 3 syntax.

Answer (score 2):

It's not currently (J 3.2) possible. Bootstrap v2.3.2 is in the core of Joomla 3.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:** I tested the below method and ran into problems. I wouldn't recommend it.

Try using a bootstrap adapter. It doesn't remove dependencies on Bootstrap 2 (BS2), but it might still help you with your problem. I'm not entirely sure how it works,but I believe it replaces the BS2 css with styles compatible with BS3.

http://about.asika.tw/bootstrap3-adapter/

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple template overrides. You can to it with very simple steps. Just do follow the Read Me :)
https://github.com/rakeshmali/joomla-bootstrap-v3-template

If found any issues just file it there you will definitely got the solution in that.